# How can I get the aggregate of two CloudWatch metrics in a single metric?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I want to get average of network input and network output metric as a single metric from Amazon CloudWatch. Is there any way to achieve this or any script or opensource tools available?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [CloudWatch Metric Math](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/using-metric-math.html) `AVG` function to get the average of two metrics:

> The AVG of a single time series returns a scalar representing the
>   average of all the data points in the metric. **The AVG of an array of
>   time series returns a single time series**. Missing values are treated
>   as 0.